# how to change html text to logo on hover

Tags: html

I can't seem to find a solution that works online so I thought I would ask on here. So, I want to have my page menu to display my logo when I hover over it. I don't mind using javascript or just plain HTML and CSS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="refrences.html">Refrences</a></li>
```

Comment: It can most likely be done with CSS only, but please share the relevant HTML.

Comment: <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="refrences.html">Refrences</a></li>

Comment: I want the code i've just posted to display my logo when someone hovers over it:

Comment: Please post your code in your question where it can be properly formatted

Comment: I want the items in within the <ul> tags to be replaced with my logo when they are hovered on by a cursor. here is my code: https://pastebin.com/bcWGKvsA if you go to http://foodcreating.com/ it shows what I am asking

Answer (score 0):

Without your code I cant give you a specific answer but you can do this pretty easily with CSS selector `:hover`. You can see how that works in this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8xxtLega/1/

If you dont want the image to take up then you can use the display property instead of opacity to hide your image. Like so:

```
img {
    display: none;
}

div:hover img {
    display: block;
}
```

The div in this instance could be your entire menu or some other kind of container. This would achieve the method you are looking for of making your image appear when you hover over your menu.

I reccomend you use opacity or `display: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` so that it doesnt change your layout when the image appears.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example solution using JQuery to replace a menu link with a logo image on hover, and when the mouse leaves the image the link is replaced. I'm sure there's better ways, but this was a quick thought after reading your last comments and edits. Hope that helps.

```js
// Requires JQuery
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $('#home').hover(
      function () {
        $('#home').html('<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" style="width:30px; height:20px;">');
      }, 
      function () {
        $('#home').html('<a href="index.html">Home</a>');
      }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 30px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul>
  <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
  <li><a href="refrences.html">Refrences</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```